# Getting problem with RMI in jmeter distributed execution

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter distributed execution could seed the below error in jmeter-serever.log of slave machine and its trying to connect the different IP 192.170.70.1 which is not configure in the jmeter.properties file of master at all.even both the master and slave is having the same version jmeter(3.1) and java(1.8.0_171),Please let me know.

```
In jmeter.propeties I have configured the different IP'S like  10.xxx.xx.xx

2018/09/06 15:40:00 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper:  java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: **192.170.70.1**; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.testEnded(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteTestListenerWrapper.testEnded(RemoteTestListenerWrapper.java:79)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:437)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Hi,I have solved the issue by setting the Java.rmi.servername.hostname in system.properties file for both master and slave,after doing this change its started working fine

Comment: In this case , answer your own question and accept it so that other know this fixed your issue. Otherwise I'll amend my answer to add this possible cause. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have a firewall between the client and the jmeter-servers.

Ensure you open:

- server_port=1099 (default value)
- server.rmi.port=0 (change value and open port)
- server.rmi.localport=0 (change value and open port)
- client.rmi.localport=0 (change value and open port)

But having a firewall between those components is not great.

Besides, you're using JMeter 3.1 which is now old, update to JMeter 4.0 or 3.3.